# Spring JPA query flexible selected column based on a value of a variable

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I would like to change the column based on the value of the searchBy variable, because the scenario is, we're not sure which column we're going to search. so I want to make the column flexible.

```
example: 

String searchBy = "id";
int value = 1;
```

My query should adjust based on these specification.

**In my Rest controller**

```
String translatedQuery = 
"SELECT b From Booking b WHERE b."+searchCriteria.getSearchBy()+
" LIKE '%"+searchCriteria.getValue()+"%'";

List<Booking> booking = bookingRepository.getSearchedBookings(translatedQuery);
```

**In my JPA Repository**

```
@Query(":translatedQuery")
public List<Booking> getSearchedBookings(String translatedQuery);
```

**Expected Query will be something like**

```
"SELECT b FROM Booking b WHERE b.id LIKE '%1%'"
```

Comment: Use Spring-Data